# Split e.location string into variables

Tags: javascript, split

I am using leaflet watch.position. It returns a value of

```
LatLng(52.409958, -1.531085)
```

I need to split is so that

```
var lat = 52.309958
var lng = -1.5310.85
```

Maybe I am being thick but I just cant do it? Any suggestion? I have tried split but no joy

Comment: The thing it returns, is it a string that looks like that?

Comment: Can you post the `split` that didn't work?

Comment: var tosplit = e.latlng;

var fields = tosplit.split(',');

var lat = fields[0];
var lng = fields[1];

Comment: The value of e.latlng is ' LatLng(52.409958, -1.531085)' Thats what I need to split

Comment: See also: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LatLng](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlng) has the following properties:

> lat   Number  Latitude in degrees
>
> lng   Number  Longitude in degrees
>
> alt Number    Altitude in meters (optional)

The solution would then be (where `obj` is the return LatLng object):

```
const lat = obj.lat;
const lng = obj.lng;
```

Or even simpler:

```
const {lat, lng} = obj;
```

Comment: Ok, but where do I use this then? I cant just add that.

Comment: @larrychambers you would have to provide more code for me to give you a more detailed answer. However, you simply use it with the watch.position return value, no?

Comment: What code shall I provide. When running leaflet in watch mode, it returns a value of e.latlng That value in this case is " LatLng(52.409958, -1.531085)" I just need to split it so that I have the lat and lng stored. Thanks

Comment: @larrychambers sorry was a bit busy. Do you still need help? If so then simply check if the return result is an instanceof String (which I HIGHLY doubt). If it is (which again I highly doubt) then you'll have to use some regex or a split method to get the different values.

Comment: Kemicofa, it works with this mate. Are you saying that way doesnt work? var test = e.latlng;
const lat = test.lat;
const lng = test.lng;

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = e.latlng;
const lat = test.lat;
const lng = test.lng;
```